# Keeping HTML div in one place

Tags: html

I want to keep several divs at one place and want to show them on clicking on the respective buttons but they are coming in a row format. Actually I want to keep then overlapping each another.

Comment: Ah, I can see your problem, you haven't written any code. That prevents the divs from overlapping anything. Try writing some code and posting it plz. Also, take a gander at the [Stack Overflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq); welcome to the community.

Comment: @zzzzBov yes I agree, the absence of any code definitely is the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use absolute positioning and z-index to put one on top of the other.

Check this example, and modify z-index to see how it changes:
http://jsfiddle.net/Pizzicato/LgN9z/

Comment: unless you use the display order and negative margins to do the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with absolute CSS positioning. [Here](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) is tutorial on this topic with examples. Overlapping of HTML elements is done through [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp) CSS property.